n-Dimensional Submanifolds with Boundary of n-Dimensional Manifolds
let $M$ be an n-dimensional manifold and let $N$ be a compact subspace of $M$ which is also (with the subspace topology) an n-dimensional manifold with boundary (for the terminology and the notation used, see the notes below). My question is the following.
Is $M \backslash Int(N)$ an n-dimensional manifold with boundary (equal to $\partial N$)?
I do not even know the answer to this question in the special case $n=2$, so any help is welcome.
Thank you very much in advance for your kind attention.
NOTE 1 By n-dimensional manifold I mean a second-countable Hausdorff space $X$ such that every point $x \in X$ has an open neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. By n-dimensional manifold with boundary I mean a second-countable Hausdorff space $X$ such that every point $x \in X$ has an open neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ or to $\mathbb{R}_{+}^n = \{(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n : x_n \geq 0 \}$. Given an n-dimensional manifold with boundary $X$, the set of all points of $X$ having an open neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ is called the interior of $X$ and denoted by $Int(X)$, while the complementary set $X \backslash Int(X)$ is called the boundary set of $X$ and denoted by $\partial X$.
NOTE 2 Under our assumptions $Int(N)$ coincides with the topological interior $I(N)$ of $N$ (that is the interior of $N$ as a subspace of the topological space $M$), while $\partial N$ coincides with the topological boundary $B(N)$ of $N$ (that is the boundary of $N$ as a subspace of the topological space $M$). The simple proof of this fact goes as follows.
Since $I(N)$ is an open subset of $M$, if $p \in I(N)$ and $U$ is an open neighborhood of $p$ in $M$ such that there exists a homeomorphsim $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, then $f(U \cap I(N))$ is an open neighborhood of $f(p)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so that there exists an open ball $B$ with center $f(p)$ contained $f(U \cap I(N))$. Then $f^{-1}(B)$ is an open neighborhood of $p$ in $I(N)$ (and so in $N$) homeomorphic to $B$, wich is in turn homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. This proves that $I(N) \subseteq Int(N)$. Assume now that $p \in Int(N)$, so that there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $p$ in $M$ such that there is a homeomorphism $g:V \cap N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Take an open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ in $M$  such that there is a homeomorphism $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Since $U \cap V \cap N$ is an open subset of $V \cap N$, $g(U \cap V \cap N)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Moreover the map $f \circ g^{-1}:g(U \cap V \cap N) \rightarrow f(U \cap V \cap N)$ is a homeomorphism, so that by the Invariance of Domain $f(U \cap V \cap N)$ turns out to be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, which in turn implies that $U \cap V \cap N$ is open in $U$ and so in $M$. Hence $U \cap V \cap N$ is an open neighborhood of $p$ contained in $N$, so that $p \in I(N)$. In conclusion $Int(N)=I(N)$. Now, since $N$ is compact and $M$ is Hausdorff, $N$ is a closed subset of $M$, so that $\{ I(N), B(N) \}$ is a partition of $N$, hence $\partial N = B(N)$.

Do you know about Schoenflies theorem and about wild spheres?

@MoisheKohan Dear Moshe, thank you for your comment. Actually, I know Schoenflies theorem in the plane, but not much more. By following your suggestion, I gave a look at the wikipedia page Alexander Horned Sphere and I was quite amazed! It is an incredible topological object, and it shows that the answer to my question is negative for $n \geq 3$. By the classification theorem for 1-dimensional maniflolds, the answer is clearly positive for $n=1$. But what happens for $n=2$? I cannot see how to use Schoenflies theorem to get a conclusion.

Schoenflies implies that the answer is positive in dimension 2 (every topological arc is locally flat).

@MoisheKohan Dear Moishe, I have finally understood what you mean! I will write down a detailed answer as soon as I can. Thank you very very ... much for your invaluable help! I could never answer this question by myself!
